# linux/module.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

i'm a beginner and i'm trying out some basics of kernel programming in linux. Today morning i've opened the module.h file in VIM, and closed without saving any changes as well. After that i'm not able to compile any of my codes. I'm getting the following error message

```
[root@localhost helloworld]# cc helloworld.c
helloworld.c:1:25: error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
[root@localhost helloworld]#
```

Here is a sample code which was running successfully till the last day.

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
        printk("HELLO WORLD");
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk("GOODBYE");
}
```

I searched for the module.h file like the following and it do exist

```
[root@localhost usr]# find . -name module.h
./src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-i686/include/asm-x86_64/module.h
./src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-i686/include/asm-i386/module.h
./src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-i686/include/linux/module.h
./include/sepol/policydb/module.h
./include/sepol/module.h
./include/kde/kunittest/module.h
[root@localhost usr]#
```

Please help me out.
I'm using CentOS in virtual box.

Comment: Please can you tell me how did you solve this ?  if you did

Answer (score 28):

You're trying to compile your module with plain `gcc` with none of the
surrounding kbuild framework. You might have gotten something to work in the
past with this approach, but it is *painful* horrible awful to try to maintain
a module using anything other than pure-kbuild `Makefile` approaches. I've
wasted too much of my life fighting against kbuild and I don't want the same to
happen with you -- embrace kbuild and let it help you build your module. Please
read `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` before writing another line of code.

What you need to do is create a `Makefile` for your module. Its contents should
look like this:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# kbuild part of makefile
obj-m  := modulename.o

else
# normal makefile
    KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

endif
```

I know it's a lot more complicated than most `Makefile`s you're used to seeing,
but it serves a dual-purpose. If you just run `make` in your directory, it'll
re-invoke `make` to use the kbuild mechanism from the currently-running kernel
(assumed to at least have a symlink from `/lib/modules/.../build` to the
correct location).

The re-invoked `make` command (`$(MAKE)`) will properly build your module and
save you more time than you can ever appreciate. (Really.)

Keep `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` by your side while making this work.

Note: `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` may be available at your linux system at `/usr/share/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt`

Comment: @ajishalfred Now you may like to accept this answer. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This answer was helpful because it specifically helped when trying to create a kernel module. But the underlying question still isn't answered. What if I'm trying to "#include <linux/socket.h>" and I get this error message? What do I do then?

Comment: @CatGuardian, hmm, good question. Do you have kernel headers package from your distribution installed that match your running kernel? Or are you installing a module against a self-compiled kernel? It'd probably be best to ask a new question if this isn't enough to help out -- that will get significantly more attention than comments buried here. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Install the package kernel-devel:

```
yum install kernel-devel
```

After that, you should have:

```
/usr/src/kernels/$kernelversion/include/linux/module.h
```

You can then pass something like:

```
-I/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include
```

to the compiler

Comment: how do i pass something to a compiler. For Ex. gcc -o hello hello.c -B  -I/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include 
where do you give the location as argument, as i am still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

You may need a Makefile to compile your module.I have tried out on my personal computer(Ubuntu 10.04.4),I meet the same problem when I use `gcc -c hello.c`,but using a Makefile, everything will be OK.The kernel vesion is 2.6.32-54-generic