# Simple Device Driver not working

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, libraries

I'm writing a basic device driver with code

```
#define MODULE
#include<linux/module.h>

int init_module(void){
    printk("<1>Hello World!!!\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
    printk("<1>Goodbye cruel world");

}
```

In Ubuntu,
It is giving an error:

```
linux/module.h no such file or directory.
```

Comment: Please paste that error message in google and look at the hits. If you still can't figure it out, please [edit] your post to tell us what you tried to solve it and how it didn't work/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux/module.h: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062601/linux-module-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and [linux/module.h No such file or Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919512/linux-module-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: What is your compilation line ? Do you specify the right include directory ?

Comment: The very first thing I want to know is your Makefile...

Answer (score 0):

This is because Linux kernel headers which is needed to compile this code against the Linux kernel is missing.
Use this command to install it:

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

(Read this [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/75854)).

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner for device drivers and upto my knowledge we required both `linux-source-tree` and `linux-kernel` to compile driver modules.

First check installed `generic-header` in `/usr/src` folder, then install source tree by this command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-tree
```

and your problem will be resolved.

More Info :

If you have installed more than `1` header, I suggest you to have the latest header. You can uninstall previous headers by this command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command removes packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed.

I hope this will help you.