# GCC Kernel Module Compilation Errors

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, netfilter

I'm working on a netfilter and compiling it on a virtual machine.

```
matt@ubuntu:~$ make
gcc -c -O2 -W -isystem /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/build/include -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE test10.c -I. 
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87/include/linux/kernel.h:6:0,
                 from structs1.h:2,
                 from test10.c:1:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
makefile:2: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Above is my GCC command used to attempt to build my kernel module and the subsequent error that it throws.

In researching this, I have found one possible solution that involves specifiying the kernel version as such:

```
KERNEL_VER=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87/arch/x86/
```

But two problems:

1. I'm not sure how to actually use this in my make file which can be seen below, outside of just making a symbolic link, and
2. I looked in this folder (`/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87/arch/x86/`) and sub folders and it doesn't have any of the same `kernel.h` files -- which is what I need.

Makefile:

```
test:
        gcc -c -O2 -W -isystem /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/build/include -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE test10.c -I.
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux/module.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062601/linux-module-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

The standard Makefile used to build a loadable kernel module is as follows.

```
obj-m += test10.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Refer [Compiling a loadable kernel module](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) this for more information.

Comment: matt@ubuntu:~$ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:199: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic'
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2


Is the error I'm getting with this

Comment: @Crumblez: Try the entire Makefile. Copy the code in the answer to a file named `Makefile` and then just run `make`